# PHP not echoing after file upload completed

Tags: php

I have some simple code to upload file using drop zone. It's uploading the file just fine but for some reason it doesn't echo "done uploading" at the end of the code.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    removedfile: function(file) { 
      var _ref;
      return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
    }
  };
</script>

<div id="dropzone">
    <form id="myDropzone" action="#" class="dropzone" id="demo-upload">
      <div class="dz-message">
        Drop files here or click to upload.<br />
      </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
    echo "done uploading";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've removed the second part of your question asking about "Best practice", as this is likely not suitable here (try codereview) but mainly as you should only have one question scope at a time (or we cannot answer or comment easily)

Comment: You need to wrap `move_uploaded_file` as follows: `if(move_uploaded_file(...)) { // done uploading } else { // failed moving }`. Furthermore, check your `$targetPath` permissions - they probably need to be 777. If that doesn't work - see if you have enough space on the hard.

Comment: yeah sorry about that it has been edited, mainly just trying to figure out why it not echoing at the end

Comment: thanks let me try that

Comment: well i don't see why file permissions would have problem with echoing php, as its uploading the file just fine.

Comment: Your `echo` is at the end of the execution. Right before that you have `move_uploaded_file` which is moving the uploaded file to a specific path. If you don't have the right permissions to that path, it will fail and therefore you won't see `done uploading`.

Comment: If I am right Dropzone uses AJAX so you can try echo JSON encoded array and catch that on your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Dropzone uses AJAX to post requests to server you will not see the response line ordinary PHP response when you echo something.

Try in this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        ...
        success: function(file, response){
            alert(response); // Just to test, you can remove this
            // Do what you want
            // Like:
            if(response == "success") {
                // Uploaded ok
            } else {
                // Failed to upload
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

In this way after successful AJAX request you can catch the response and do whatever you want.

Ofcoruse, like @tftd said, You need to wrap `move_uploaded_file` like:

```
if(move_uploaded_file(...)) {
    // done uploading
    echo json_encode('success');
} else {
    // failed moving
    echo json_encode('error');
}
```

Comment: ok so i didn't really needed remove links stuff so i removed that and just put  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            success: function(file, response){
                alert(response);
            }
        }; and it alerted my whole html code instead of echo in if statement, so i guess close to solution now?

Comment: alert(response) is just for testing. You can remove alert(response) and do with response whatever you want.

Comment: ok got it to work thanks, one quick question instead of whole page response how can i only get the value that I'm echoing? because i like to get that value and pass that as GET parameter in redirect on success

Comment: StackOverflow is not a chat, you should open another question so we can answer that but first try to search if someone already asked that and got the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)) {
    echo "done uploading";
} else {
    echo 'error!';
}
```

You can activate [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to see the error from `move_uploaded_file`

## Edit: Ugly hack, just for testing. DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION!!!

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)) {
    $_SESSION["success"] = "upload done";
    echo $_SESSION["success];
} else {
    echo 'error!';
}
```

Comment: i switched the if to this and it uploaded the file but didn't echo anything

Comment: Have a look at another of my posts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045233/php-ftp-put-uploading-to-directory/31179518#31179518 It might be helpful

Comment: thanks for the reply but if i have just regular html form with php its working just fine, but this drop zone thing has been giving me hassle for while now.

Comment: Check your console for redirects?

Comment: session didn't echo :(  and yes i close the quotation in echo line.